# Calculating multiindex series / dataframes with conditions

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a multiindex Sries that I would like to make calculations on it. I'm not familiar with multiindex dataframes, some advice will be much appreciated.

```
d = {'c1':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd'], 'c2':['False', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False']}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dd.groupby('c1')['c2'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

```
c1  c2   
a   False    0.500000
    True     0.500000
b   True     1.000000
c   True     0.666667
    False    0.333333
d   False    1.000000
```

I'd like to take the max number with `True` in the `c2` column divides by other numbers with `True`.
For the above example, it will be `1 / 0.500000` and `1 / 0.666667`

Expected output

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, all you have to do is use the `.xs` method on your value counts.

Take:

```
series = dd.groupby('c1')['c2'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

To get the number of `True`s by `c1` you can do

```
true_counts = series.xs('True', level=1)
```

Which returns something like this:

```
c1
a    0.500000
b    1.000000
c    0.666667
Name: c2, dtype: float64
```

Now you can do all your operations on a single index Series. Start by taking the `max_index` and `max_value`, which, in this case (because it's normalized), could be achieved by `true_counts.loc[true_counts == 1]` and then retrieving the values and index, or:

```
max_index = true_counts.index[true_counts.argmax()]
max_val = true_counts[max_index]
```

And then, doing the calculation over the remaining rows:

```
true_counts_dropped = true_counts.drop(max_index)
ans = max_val / true_counts_dropped
```

To make the index look like `b/a`, `b/c`, you can do:

```
ans.index = [max_index + '/' + idx for idx in ans.index]
```

And the final result:

```
>>> ans
b/a    2.0
b/c    1.5
Name: c2, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to achieve the expected output is turning your indexes into columns. You could try out something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'c1':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd'], 
     'c2':['False', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False']}

dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

dd = dd.groupby('c1')['c2'].value_counts(normalize=True).to_frame()

dd.rename(columns={"c2": "freq"}, inplace=True)

dd.reset_index(inplace=True)

max_true = max(dd.loc[dd["c2"] == "True"]["freq"])

dd2 = dd.copy()
dd2["result"] = max_true/dd2[["freq"]]
dd2.loc[dd2["c2"]!="True","result"] = None
```

As a result you get:

```
>>> print(max_true)
1.0

>>> print(dd)
  c1     c2      freq
0  a  False  0.500000
1  a   True  0.500000
2  b   True  1.000000
3  c   True  0.666667
4  c  False  0.333333
5  d  False  1.000000

>>> print(dd2)
  c1     c2      freq  result
0  a  False  0.500000     NaN
1  a   True  0.500000     2.0
2  b   True  1.000000     1.0
3  c   True  0.666667     1.5
4  c  False  0.333333     NaN
5  d  False  1.000000     NaN
```

Comment: thank you. Perhaps `max(dd.loc[dd["c2"] == "True"]["freq"])` should be `dd.loc[dd["c2"] == "True"]["freq"].max()` ? I'm getting `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` from the first one.

Comment: Both options are working here. I'm using Python 3.9.0

Answer (score 0):

You could continue on from your `value_counts` and unstack the first index before creating a new dataframe:

```
reshape = (dd.groupby("c1")["c2"]
             .value_counts(normalize=True)
             .unstack("c1")
             .loc["True"])

mapping = {"Calculation": ["b/a", "b/c"],
            "Ans": [reshape["b"] / reshape["a"], 
                    reshape["b"] / reshape["c"]],
           }

pd.DataFrame(mapping)

Calculation     Ans
0   b/a     2.0
1   b/c     1.5
```